# obabel doesn't split molecules

Tags: computational-chemistry

I have a .xyz input file

```
8
Energy =
C     0.0354972    0.7111560   -1.7500000
C    -0.0354972   -0.7111560   -1.7500000
C     1.1823040   -1.4277968   -1.7500000
C     2.3594716   -0.7301614   -1.7500000
C     0.0354972    0.7111560    1.7500000
C    -0.0354972   -0.7111560    1.7500000
C     1.1823040   -1.4277968    1.7500000
C     2.3594716   -0.7301614    1.7500000
```

(this is shortened, problem stays the same) which I would like to split with obabel. However, with

```
obabel coord.xyz -o split.xyz --seperate -m
```

I only get one outputfile `split1.xyz` containing the whole supermolecule. This is also the case if I enlargen the z-distance between the two molecules.

Does anybody either:

- Know why this doesn't work
- Has a different program which I can use

I don't have the time to manually split 500 molecule files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not knowing which version you are running, it is difficult to actually help you.

I am using Open Babel 2.4.1, and had absolutely no problem separating the two ethylene fragments from the following file (`super.xyz`):

```
12
symmetry c1
C       -0.498388809     -1.662363855     -2.140955132
C       -0.498388809     -1.662363855     -0.810797132
H       -0.498388809     -0.739022855     -2.713905132
H       -0.498388809     -2.585704855     -2.713905132
H       -0.498388809     -0.739022855     -0.237847132
H       -0.498388809     -2.585704855     -0.237847132
C        1.730729269     -0.175065928     -2.629761741
C        1.730729269     -0.175065928     -1.299603741
H        1.730729269      0.748275072     -3.202711741
H        1.730729269     -1.098406928     -3.202711741
H        1.730729269      0.748275072     -0.726653741
H        1.730729269     -1.098406928     -0.726653741
```

Using the command

```
$ obabel super.xyz -Ofrag.xyz --separate -m
```

results in `frag1.xyz` and `frag2.xyz` containing one ethylene each.

Comment: I'm using 2.3.2. Your input file with your command works. This helps me debug the problem at least, thank you.

Comment: @Fl.pf. your input worked for me, too (after fixing the atom count). Maybe it's the lower case o which should indicate the file type, not the output location.

Comment: yeah that, and the fact that I'm an idiot (it's --separate, not --seperate). Thanks for being my rubber ducky though :D